# How to convert null value to default(float) 0.0 value and should save that default value into MYSql version(6.0.11-alpha-community)

Tags: c#, console-application

Dynamically reading the excel data (from filezilla) and saving into mysql version (6.0.11-alpha-community)

I'm using the stored procedure (to capture the Excel.csv data) and save it into mysql version (6.0.11-alpha-community)

but while I'm executing or saving the data into mysql I'm getting this error:

[image: Input string was not in a correct format]

In the above image 2021070701.csv and 2021070801.csv are reading and saving into mysql is fine because there is no null data in the excel file (particular cell).

when it reach the execution to this file 2021070201.csv I'm getting the "Format exception error"

The 2021070201.csv(excel) data look like this format:
(2021070201.csv excel data and blue highlighted cells are float values and the cells contains null data)

[image: 2021070201.csv excel data and blue highlighted cells are float values and the cells contains null data]

This is what I written logic to read the excel data and saving into mysql

```
  else if (mpType.Equals("Indices", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        MAE_Repo.InsertNseIndicesPrice("Usp_tbl_Intraday_NseIndicesPrice", 0, Convert.ToInt32(res[0]), res[1], Convert.ToSingle(res[2]),
     Convert.ToSingle(res[3]), Convert.ToSingle(res[4]), Convert.ToSingle(res[5]), Convert.ToSingle(res[6]),
     Convert.ToSingle(res[7]), Convert.ToSingle(res[8]), Convert.ToSingle(res[9]), Convert.ToSingle(res[10]),
     Convert.ToDateTime(res[11]), res[12], timeStamp, filename);
    }
```

And this is what I written the SP logic:

```
 Public static void InsertNseIndicesPrice(String ProcName, int ipID, int ipIndextoken, string ipSymbol, float ipCLOSE,
          float ipOPEN, float ipHigh,float ipLow, float ipVolume, float ipVALUE, float ipprev_close, float ipCHANGE, float ipPer_Change, 
          DateTime ipUpdtime, string ipFlag, DateTime ipCreatedOn, string ipFileName)
        {
            con.Open();
            MySqlCommand cmdSel = new MySqlCommand(ProcName, con);
            cmdSel.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmdSel.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IPID", 0);
            cmdSel.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IPIndextoken", ipIndextoken);
            cmdSel.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IPSymbol", ipSymbol);
            cmdSel.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IPCLOSE", ipCLOSE);
            cmdSel.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IPOPEN", ipOPEN);
            cmdSel.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IPHigh", ipHigh);
            cmdSel.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IPLow", ipLow);
            cmdSel.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IPVolume", ipVolume);
            cmdSel.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IPVALUE", ipVALUE);
            cmdSel.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IPprev_close", ipprev_close);
            cmdSel.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IPCHANGE", ipCHANGE);
            cmdSel.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IPPer_Change", ipPer_Change);
            cmdSel.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IPUpdtime", ipUpdtime);
            cmdSel.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IPFlag", ipFlag);
            cmdSel.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IPCreatedOn", ipCreatedOn);
            cmdSel.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IPFileName", ipFileName);
            cmdSel.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OPType", 1);


            MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmdSel);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            con.Close();
        }
```

And this is my stored Procedure in mysql

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `marketprice_nse`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `Usp_tbl_Intraday_NseIndicesPrice`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `Usp_tbl_Intraday_NseIndicesPrice`(IN IPID BIGINT, IN IPIndextoken INT, IN IPSymbol VARCHAR(20), IN IPCLOSE FLOAT,
    IN IPOPEN FLOAT, IN IPHigh FLOAT,IN IPLow FLOAT, IN IPVolume FLOAT, IN IPVALUE FLOAT,IN IPprev_close FLOAT, IN IPCHANGE FLOAT, IN IPPer_Change FLOAT, 
    IN IPUpdtime DATETIME, IN IPFlag VARCHAR(1), IN IPCreatedOn DATETIME, IN IPFileName VARCHAR(30),IN OPType INT)
BEGIN
IF (OPType = 1)-- Insert
THEN
     -- IF (SELECT 1 FROM tbl_intraday_nseindicesprice WHERE FileName = IPFileName) = 0
     -- THEN
     -- BEGIN
        INSERT INTO tbl_Intraday_NseIndicesPrice (ID, Indextoken, Symbol, `CLOSE`, `OPEN`, High, Low, Volume, `VALUE`, prev_close, `CHANGE`,
         Per_Change, Updtime, Flag, CreatedOn, FileName) VALUES (IPID, IPIndextoken, IPSymbol, IPCLOSE, IPOPEN, IPHigh, IPLow, IPVolume, 
         IPVALUE, IPprev_close, IPCHANGE, IPPer_Change, IPUpdtime, IPFlag, IPCreatedOn, IPFileName);
         
      -- END;
      -- END IF;     
      
ELSEIF (OPType = 2)-- Check FileName availability 
THEN
SELECT * FROM tbl_intraday_nseindicesprice WHERE FileName=IPFileName;
END IF;
      
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

I tried different ways like

```
Single.Parse() Method
float.Parse() Method
Convert.ToSingle() Method
```

these methods are not solved the format exception

How can I save the default value(0.0) into mysql with out any format exception?

Comment: When you have an empty cell, is the value like ``res[6]`` null or an empty string? If it is null, you could write ``Convert.ToSingle(res[6] ?? "0.0")``.   If it is an empty string, you could do something like  ``Convert.ToSingle(string.IsNullOrEmpty(res[6]) ? "0.0" : res[6])``

Comment: Yes, it is an empty string and "Convert.ToSingle(string.IsNullOrEmpty(res[6]) ? "0.0" : res[6])" this is one is helped .

Answer (score 0):

OK based on the comments this is the answer:

Instead of writing `Convert.ToSingle(res[6])` you can write  `Convert.ToSingle(res[6] ?? "0.0")`. Then if the value of res[6] is null, the string "0.0" will be used converted to a single instead.

If you need to worry about various locales having period or comma as decimal separator, you could simply use "0" as the default (which will also convert to a 0.0 float), or create a string having the local decimal separator

```
    string defaultFloatValue = (0.0F).toString();
```

and use it instead of the "0.0" literal.